# How to place an heading image behind make title?

Tags: graphics, titles, backgrounds

I'm trying to insert an image behind my \maketitle, right on top of the page, but i cannot do this yet, how could I do it?

My actual code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example.png}}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place the image using [`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) in the `B`ack`G`round of the first page only (using the starred `*` version):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,eso-pic}

\title{A title}
\author{An author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \AtTextLowerLeft{%
    \makebox[\textwidth]{%
      \raisebox{\dimexpr\textheight-\height}{\includegraphics[width=200pt]{example-image}}%
    }%
  }%
}
\maketitle

\section{A section}

\end{document}
```

The above code places the image at the top (via `\raisebox`) and in the center (via `\makebox`) of the text block, hanging down over (behind) the `\maketitle`.

Comment: Thanks @Werner! Do you have any ideia of how can I insert a background image only in the first page and another one in the whole document after the first page?